# Is merging in JPA ever necessary for attached entities?

Tags: java, jpa

Is it correct that I never need to use `EntityManager#merge()`, as long as I only deal with <strike>attached</strike> managed entities? In other words, calling `merge()` on an <strike>attached</strike> managed entity has no effect?

Or are there circumstances where merging would serve a purpose? I find the name suggests that I could use it to deal with an `OptimisticLockException`... :)

**Edit**: In very simple terms, my understanding of a *managed Entity* is that modifications of its properties/fields get persisted to the DB at the end of the transaction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The specification states that:

> If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge
>   operation, however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities
>   referenced by relationships from X if these relationships have been
>   annotated with the cascade element value `cascade=MERGE` or
>   `cascade=ALL` annotation.

Comment: Thx! Managed == attached? Could you please elaborate regarding cascade-to-referenced-entities (or point me towards material to read)?  I would assume that for an attached entity, all referenced entities are also attached...

Comment: managed is attached, yes. Reference material ? the JPA spec perhaps ... just search in it for "merge".

Comment: Depends what JPA implementation you are using but `Managed != attached`. If you send a entity out of context (say with a service call) and receive it back later it will be attached to the persistence context, but does not become managed again until a `merge` is called on it. [EntityManager.Contains](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) will tell you if the object is managed.

Comment: The OP used terminology "attached" so you have to ask him what he understands by that, but then you haven't defined what you mean by it either :-). As far as DataNucleus JPA is concerned any persistable object that is not detached and is persistent is "attached" (or "managed" if we use what the JPA spec says - not saying if managed by the same EM, just that it is "managed"). Note that the JPA spec does not refer to "attached", just "detached". Passing objects out of persistence context will detach them, by the spec.

Comment: Apologies, I've corrected the OP, was confused by EntityManager.detach(), expecting the antonym to be *attached*. I've also added my understanding of *managed*. I currently use EclipseLink, how's that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Many years later ....

Regarding the specification

> If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,
>   however, the merge operation is cascaded to entities referenced by
>   relationships from X if these relationships have been annotated with
>   the cascade element value cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL annotation.

Consider this...

- Object X is managed and has a OneToMany relationship to object Y with
  cascade=MERGE
- Initially when object of type X is created there is no related Y.
- Object X is persisted.
- Later object Y is created and a reference added to X.

It is my understanding that a merge is the correct operation to perform to persist all changes at this stage, so a merge can be called on managed entities in some cases.

[image]